# Como faço para colocar a div, no topo da página, tocando mesmo no topo

Tags: html, css

Bom, eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<style>
body{
background-image: url("imagens/fundo.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}   


.logo{
margin-left:10%;    

}

.linha1{
margin-left:20%;
background-color:#ABABAB;   
height:5%;
width:20%;
margin-top:0%;
}

.online{
margin-left:60%;
margin-top:1%;
}

.jack1{
background-color:#ABABAB;   
height:5%;
width:20%;
margin-left:10%;
}

</style>
<header>
<div class="jack1">


</div>


<div class="online">
<span style="color:#a9a9a9; font-family:proxima_nova_cn_rgregular,sans-serif; font-size:18px; text-transform: uppercase;">Online:</span>
<span style="color:#a9a9a9; font-family:proxima_nova_cn_rgregular,sans-serif; font-size:17px; text-transform: uppercase;"><b>20</b></span>  
</div>





<div class="logo">
<img src="imagens/logo.png">
</div>


</header>
```

O que pretendo fazer, é colocar a div jack1, no topo da página, tocando mesmo. Pois o que me está a aparecer é com um espaçamentos de alguns pixeis.

Como posso fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: Onde está no HTML essa div?

Comment: Atualizei o post, tinha colocado o código errado. Obrigado Miguel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que tens de fazer simplesmente é colocar o body com `margin: 0;`, este por *default* tem uma margem de 8px (se não estou em erro):

```
body{
    background-image: url("imagens/fundo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: É isso mesmo, obrigado pela ajuda Miguel, brevemente aceito a resposta.

Comment: De nada @Gonçalo, ainda bem que ajudei, está descansado que isto nunca mais esqueces

Comment: Eheheh, é verdade.